# parse-push-plugin not passing device token to database

Tags: firebase, parsing, plugins, push, parse-server

Does anyone know why the device token is not getting passed to the database?

parse server 3.10.0
ionic 1
cordova

https://github.com/taivo/parse-push-plugin

some further debugging has found this error

W/FirebaseApp(): Default FirebaseApp failed to initialize because no default options were found. This usually means that com.google.gms:google-services was not applied to your gradle project.

I/FirebaseInitProvider(): FirebaseApp initialization unsuccessful

Comment: I think this is not related to Parse Server, are you sure you are setting credentials correct for Firebase ?